# set a path according to the user for a folder

Tags: r

I have a script that I am setting a path to where the datasets I will work on, but now the scripts will start to be run by other people on the team, how do I leave the folder with dynamic value according to the user who uses the script.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Jonas/Database")
```

I'm even creating a variable to receive the user of the machine, but I don't know how to add this to setwd

```
u <- Sys.info()["user"]
```

I tried to do that but was unsuccessful.

```
setwd("C:/Users/u/Database")
```

Comment: `setwd(paste0("C:/Users/", u, "/Database"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use paste0

```
u <- Sys.info()["user"]


setwd(paste0("C:/Users/",u))
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, what would be the solution if the user was not the last character, example:
setwd ("C: / Users /Jonas/ Database)